# How to draw an arrow from one div to another in React dynamic JSX?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a react app with some dynamic divs coming from a function that processes a dataset to be connected via arrows. Each div is a "Question" and each question has "answers" and each answer has its sub-question. The relationship between sub-questions and answers is, each answer and the related sub-question has the same id with different prefixes (if the answer has id "option8", the related sub-question is "q8"). **The problem is, the function is running, but can't see any arrow.**

**But when I try with static HTML div ids, arrows can be seen properly**

I found the npm module "react-dom-arrow" and created a function to map each answer and its sub-question and draw an arrow as follows.

```
drawArrows = () => {
    const questionsList = this.state.questionsData;
    return questionsList.map(each => {
        return (
            <Arrow
                fromSelector={`#option${each.order}`}
                fromSide={'right'}
                toSelector={`#q${each.order}`}
                toSide={'left'}
                color={'blue'}
                stroke={3}
            />
        )
    });
}

render () {
    return (
       ...code
       { this.drawArrows() }
    )
}
```

I thought to go with my own SVG arrow method, but don't have a proper idea that how to create SVGs with div ids. How can I solve this even in a different way?

Comment: drawArrows doesn't return anything.

Comment: @jonrsharpe why is that? What's wrong?

Comment: The answer to both questions is: whoever wrote it didn't include a return statement.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I thought that return inside the map is enough. I Will try with an outside return

Comment: That returns from the callback to map, which is a *different function* to drawArrows.

Comment: @jonrsharpe got it! I edited my question by adding the return and still the arrows are not seeing

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanx for the help. Now it's working. Just a matter of re-rendering the component